# Замен текста в столбце с помощью Jquery

Tags: jquery

Есть такой столбец

```
<td id="sex">@person.Sex</td>
```

Выводиться туда 0 или 1 или вообще пусто. Какую мне функцию мне написать,чтобы заменить к примеру 0 на строку "ноль", 1 на строку "единица", а пустоту на "пусто".

Comment: а почему вы через select не хотите оформить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделал `div` вместо `td`... Но принцип-то не меняется :)

```js
$('.sex').each(function() {
  switch ($(this).html()) {
    case '0':
      $(this).html('ноль');
      break;
    case '1':
      $(this).html('единица');
      break;
    default:
      $(this).html('пусто');
      break;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sex">1</div>
<div class="sex">0</div>
<div class="sex"></div>
<div class="sex">1</div>
<div class="sex">0</div>
```

Comment: А как для каждого элемента ?

Comment: Он меняет только первый элемент в столбце

Comment: В задании Вы написали `id="sex"`, однако `id` должен быть уникален на странице. Вам следует сменить `id` на `class`. Я изменил ответ - посмотрите.